# Concatenating Data Frames in try/except block

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull data from an API and, if successful, concatenate the results into one large data frame. Here is an example of the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
year = 2000
while year < 2018:
    sqft = 1000
    while sqft < 1500:
        #will include buildHttp code if helpful to this problem
        http = buildHttp(sqft,year)
        try:
            tempDf = pd.read_csv(http)
        except:
            print("No properties matching year or sqft")
            sqft = sqft + 11
        else:
            pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(http)], ignore_index = True)
            sqft = sqft + 11
    year = year + 1
```

`buildHttp` is a function the builds a string that I can the pass to the API to try and pull data. We aren't guaranteed that a property has sold with the given sqft or in the given year and will throw an EmptyDataFrame error if so. I have a few test cases of `year` and `sqft` that didn't throw an error and can confirm `buildHttp` does build the appropriate http such that `pd.read_csv(http)` pulls data successfully. Only the successfully pulled data frames aren't appearing in `df` once done. Am I going about combining these data frames correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

One, you're not assigning the result of the concatenation to a variable. You want

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(http)], ignore_index = True)
```

Secondly, constructing the data frames, and doing the concatenation are expensive. You can speed the code up by only constructing the frame once, and then doing a single concatenation at the end.

```
frames = list()
year = 2000
while year < 2018:
    sqft = 1000
    while sqft < 1500:
        #will include buildHttp code if helpful to this problem
        http = buildHttp(sqft,year)
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(http)
        except:
            print("No properties matching year or sqft")
        else:
            frames.append(df)
        finally:
            sqft = sqft + 11
   year = year + 1
df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```